# Producing pdf report from python with bullet points

Tags: python, pdf

I would like to produce a dynamic pdf document from a python script that looks like the image below. Each sentence starts with a bullet point, and the text and number of lines depends on what the user specifies. Any suggestions or ideas as to how I can produce this from python? I'm currently looking at appy.pod and reportlab, does anyone know how to produce the bullet points?

[image]

Comment: `u'\u2022 First sentence'`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use the unicode bullet point character •

To use unicode characters in python, you can either specify the character directly or use its unicode code point.

```
u'•' == u'\u2022'
```

For example:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

c = canvas.Canvas("test.pdf")
c.drawString(100, 100, u'\u2022 First sentence')
c.save()
```