# PYTHON: How can I display dot points in python text

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am using tkinter to create a simple gui, and am wondering how I can create dot point lists in the text

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Unicode for that.

```
u'•' == u'\u2022
```

Please check this [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149153/producing-pdf-report-from-python-with-bullet-points)